# Suppose $X$ is a continuous random variable with pdf $f$ and cdf $F$. What is $\int F(a+bx)f(x) dx$ where $a, b$ are constants?

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ is a continuous random variable with pdf $f$ and cdf $F$. Therefore, $F'(x) = f(x)$ wherever the cdf is continuous.

What is $\int F(a+bx)f(x) dx$ where $a, b$ are constants. Suppose $X$ is normally distributed and here's what I have so far:

Let $u = a + bx$, then $du = b dx,$

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(a+bx)f(x) dx &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{b} F(u)f\left(\frac{u-a}{b}\right) du
\end{align*}$$

It doesn't look like $u$-substitution got me anywhere? If I set $u = F(a+bx)$, then $du = bf(a + bx)dx$ which also doesn't seem to simplify things a whole lot.

Comment: the expression $\int_x$ doesnt make sense, specially when $x$ is the variable of integration

Comment: I meant for it to be the integration over the support of $X$. I'll change it.

Comment: you dont need to note that, as $f(x)=0$ outside of the support of $X$

Comment: yes, that's fair :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developing a bit the expression the unique thing that I can see here is that

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}F(a+bx)f(x)\,d x=\int_{\{(x,y): y\leqslant a+bx\}}f(x)f(y)d(x,y)=\Pr [Y\leqslant a+bX]
$$

where $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with the same distribution. I dont think we can say something more.

EDIT: ok, I didn't read that $X$ is normally distributed, then in this case we can say  A LOT more, as $Z:=bX-Y$ will be normally distributed also with mean $b\mu_X-\mu_Y$ and variance $b^2\sigma ^2_X+\sigma ^2_Y$.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on where you got the expression for $Z$? And how it relates to the original integral?

Comment: I defined $Z$ as $bX-Y$, this is what the symbol $:=$ means, then with this definition we have that $\Pr [Y\leqslant a+bX]=\Pr [Z\geqslant -a]=1-\Pr [Z<-a]=1-\Pr [Z\leqslant -a]$, where the last equality follows because $Z$ is a continuous random variable